# Custom Adapter for Android fragment with ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, baseadapter

i'm trying to implement something like this - [have a look](http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/G0EY2I.png).
This is my BaseAdapter class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
LayoutInflater in = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder view;
    if (convertView == null) {

        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = in.inflate(R.layout.country_row, null);

        view.txtView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.countryName);

        view.txtView.setText(countryName[position]);

        convertView.setTag(view);

    } else {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    view.imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.countryImage);
    view.imgView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return convertView;
}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.india_flag,
        R.drawable.china_flag, R.drawable.argentina_flag,
        R.drawable.england_flag, R.drawable.france_flag,
        R.drawable.united_states_flag, R.drawable.uruguay_flag,
        R.drawable.pakistan_flag, R.drawable.united_kingdom_flag,
        R.drawable.italy_flag, R.drawable.germany_flag,
        R.drawable.brazil_flag, R.drawable.belgium_flag,
        R.drawable.denmark_flag, R.drawable.czech_republic_flag,
        R.drawable.jamaica_flag, R.drawable.indonesia_flag,
        R.drawable.kenya_flag, R.drawable.korea_flag,
        R.drawable.ireland_flag,

};
private String[] countryName = { "India", "China", "Argentina", "England",
        "France", "United States", "Uruguay", "Pakistan", "United Kingdom",
        "Italy", "Germany", "Brazil", "Belgium", "Denmark",
        "Czech Republic", "Jamaica", "Indonesia", "Kenya", "Korea",
        "Ireland"

};

public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imgView;
    public TextView txtView;
}
```

country_row.xml contains **ImageView and TextView**.
 Countries class extends Fragment and counties.xml contains **GridView** (I guess something i messing up here in this class, but i could't able to correct it)

```
public class Countries extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.countries,container,false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext())); 
    return view;


}
```

}
**country_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:id="@+id/countryImage"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/countryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/countryImage"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"></TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**countries.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="130dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">

  <fragment 
  android:name="com.example.fragmentsproject.Countries"
  android:id="@+id/frag1"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<fragment 
  android:name="com.example.fragmentsproject.Capitals"
  android:id="@+id/frag2"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivty**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

And this is my logcat

```
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentsproject/com.example.fragmentsproject.MainActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
```

Please someone help me,
 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove this line in GridView tag    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" and try.

Comment: That didn't work for me!

Comment: What namespaces Countries and Capitals are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause in the trace provided by you is "02-20 17:44:50.576: E/AndroidRuntime(1362): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment", 
so ensure, you're using:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

as a class to extend with your Countries class. Also Activity that uses fragments should extends FragmentActivity instead of the regular Activity. Import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

In addition I do not recommend you to initialize class fields this way:

```
LayoutInflater in = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

because of mContext field can hold null reference after constructor invocation. Better do some conditional check in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"** from your GridView declaration. Also I suggest to change

> gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext()));

to this

> gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

Answer (score 0):

put your LayoutInflater into getView

like,

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater in = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```